# Google authentification always ask authorization

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth

After having connected a user from Google OAuth, when this one wishes to reconnect during a next session requiring the selection of his google account, the permission is asked again.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#prompt), the behavior of the parameter **prompt** that is responsible for authorization requests is as follows:

> If no value is specified and the user has not previously authorized
>   access, then the user is shown a consent screen.

The user should therefore not have to reorder his consent.

The only answer envisaged was the one on this question : [login with google always asks user consent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14923799/login-with-google-always-asks-user-consent)

Because I also work locally without secure HTTP, but he assumes that a cookie policy is present which is not the case.

*How could I do to resolve this anomaly ?*

**Edit :**

```
/**
 * Create a new OAuth2Client with the credentials previously loads
 */
private getOAuth2() : OAuth2Client {
    return new OAuth2(
        this.credentials.client_secret,
        this.credentials.client_id,
        this.credentials.redirect_uris[0]
    );
}

/**
 * Create connection URL for the given scopes
 * @param scopes
 */
public url(scopes: Array<string>) : string {
    return this.client.generateAuthUrl({
            access_type: "offline",
            scope: scopes
    });
}



// The scope used to generate URL is 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'

// this.client refer to a client which is load by getOAuth2
// and use only for the generation of URL's.
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you are using to authenticate.  This is not enough information to find the problem in your code.

Comment: Doesn't the only thing that can influence is the generation of the URL ?